# What exactly does the eventTarget of the MouseWheel module in swiperjs do?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

From what i understood, it transfers the ability to control the swiper with your mousewheel to any desired element by declaring it in the parameter as eventTarget: '.class' or id etc, but it doesnt seem to change anything when I add the parameter. So what exactly does it do and what am I missing if it actually does what Ive understood it is supposed to?

Tried adding the parameter, did nothing so im asking whether my assumption of its functionality or my way of use is false.